# How can I check what parameter is finally passed with the query?

Tags: java, hibernate, time

Is there any way I can check, how is the query being framed or what values are being passed ? I want to check for this query :

```
String hql = "from Scheduled where stime <= current_time()"; // QUERY

List list = session.createQuery(hql).list();
```

I want to know what value of `current_time()` is being sent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current_time()` is not replaced with a specific time in hibernate - it is passed as part of the SQL to the database and is evaluated there. Therefore, `current_time()` will be whatever the current time is on the database server at the time the statement is executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable [Hibernate logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging) and these two params should be of help to you:

- `org.hibernate.SQL`   - Log all SQL DML statements as they are
  executed
- `org.hibernate.type` - Log all JDBC parameters

Answer (score 0):

If your underlying database is SQL Server, then another option is SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Here are entries from log4j.properties which works for me to print hibernate queries and parameters.

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE,stdout
```